# Windows 11 crashes when I turn off windows features

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

I have recently updated my windows 10 laptop to windows 11.

Now, I wanted to run VM virtual box on my Laptop and hence I turned off these Microsoft Features: Windows Hypervisor Platform and Virtual Machine Platform along with Hyper-V based on some suggestions from stackoverflow.com.

After that when I rebooted my pc; after 30% progress, my PC went black. I waited for around 30 mins but the screen was still black, I tried shutting down it forcefully by pressing the power button. Now when I open my pc, it shows the HP symbol but does not proceed further and I can just see the same black screen

Please suggest what can be done!

Comment: I can't even open my laptop now!

Comment: Turning those features off are unnecessary to run VirtualBox since the current version is compatible with those optional features. The advice you received was outdated, however, your inability to boot likely isn’t directly linked to following the advice.  You already had system problems, you just happened to follow advice, that required you to reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've bricked the system somehow. Either this is a bug from Win11 which has to be reported, or your luck.

What I would suggest is booting the system from a bootable USB to save the personal files you need and then do a fresh install of Windows (either 10 or 11).

Or try a repair install, but I am not a big fan of that. Fresh install is always **cleaner**.